# Is it possible to change a tkinter ListBox's selectmode during execution?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, widget

Let's asume a simple `tkinter` form initially defined with a `Listbox` widget in `selectmode=EXTENDED`. I want to code a button which will add Advanced options to the form and thus force the user to select a single item of the list. This translates into changing to `selectmode=SINGLE`.

My code is not working. Maybe I simply cannot redefine the `Listbox` and I should access the parameter `selectmode` some other way?

```
class DefineMultiSelectForm(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, listtodisplay=[]):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=master)
        self.listtodisplay=listtodisplay
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.listbox = Listbox(self,selectmode=EXTENDED, width=50)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.advanced_butt = Button(self, text="Advanced Editing", command=self.advanced)
        self.advanced_butt.grid (row=7, column=2, sticky=W+E)
        self.simplifd_butt = Button(self, text="Simple Editing", command=self.simple)
        self.simplifd_butt.grid (row=7, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    def advanced(self):
        self.listbox = Listbox(self,selectmode=SINGLE, width=50)

    def simple(self):
        self.listbox = Listbox(self,selectmode=EXTENDED, width=50)
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure about the `selectmode` attitude, but for most tkinter attributes you can change it like this:

```
self.listbox['selectmode'] = SINGLE
# or you can do it this way
self.listbox.config(selectmode = SINGLE)
```

The reason why your way doesn’t work is what you have said, you are redefining the variable.